# Code for four road junction

Tags: arduino-mega

This is the Arduino code for a four road junction. In the below code, the `if` case must be tested after every road without delay. Can any one guide me?

```
int redLed1 = 7; 
int yellowLed1 = 6; 
int greenLed1 = 5;
int redLed2 = 4; 
int yellowLed2 = 3; 
int greenLed2 = 2;
int redLed3 =8 ; 
int yellowLed3 =9; 
int greenLed3 =10;
int redLed4 = 14; 
int yellowLed4 = 15; 
int greenLed4 =16;
int THRESHOLD=700;
int soundvalue=0;
void setup()
{ 
    pinMode(redLed1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(yellowLed1, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(greenLed1, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(redLed2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(yellowLed2, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(greenLed2, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(redLed3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(yellowLed3, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(greenLed3, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(redLed4, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(yellowLed4, OUTPUT); 
    pinMode(greenLed4, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{ 
    digitalWrite(redLed2,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLed3,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLed4,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLed1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yellowLed1,HIGH);
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(redLed1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowLed1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLed1,HIGH);
    if(analogRead(A0)>=THRESHOLD)
    {
        digitalWrite(greenLed2,LOW);
        digitalWrite(greenLed1,HIGH);
        delay(10000);
        digitalWrite(greenLed1,LOW);
    }
    delay(30000);
    digitalWrite(greenLed1,LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLed1,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yellowLed2,HIGH);
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(redLed2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowLed2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLed2,HIGH);

    delay(30000);
    digitalWrite(greenLed2,LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLed2,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yellowLed3,HIGH);
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(redLed3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowLed3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLed3,HIGH);

    delay(30000);
    digitalWrite(greenLed3,LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLed3,HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yellowLed4,HIGH);
    delay(5000);
    digitalWrite(redLed4,LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowLed4,LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLed4,HIGH);
    delay(30000);
    digitalWrite(greenled4,LOW);

    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're asking. Can you edit your question to explain it more clearly please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what a “road” condition is, so I don't know where the “after every road” points in your code are located.  However, you can write a properly-parameterized function to do tests, or a subroutine to do tests and perform actions.  Then place a function or subroutine call whereever you need to perform the test.

Note, the first 14 lines of your code (which define 14 variables that you probably should have defined as constants) could be replaced by an `enum` statement (which defines integer constants) like

```
enum { redLed1=7, yellowLed1=6, greenLed1=5, redLed2=4, yellowLed2=3, greenLed2=2, redLed3=8, yellowLed3=9, greenLed3=10, redLed4=14, yellowLed4=15, greenLed4=16, THRESHOLD=700, soundvalue=0 };
```

or (because `enum` will advance by 1 unit when a value isn't specified) you could say

```
enum { greenLed2=2, yellowLed2, redLed2, greenLed1, yellowLed1, redLed1, redLed3, yellowLed3, greenLed3, redLed4=14, yellowLed4, greenLed4, THRESHOLD=700, soundvalue=0 };
```

For a short sketch like this, the compiler can detect that some of your variables actually are constants, but in general using constants as constants and variables as variables will produce smaller and safer code.

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: all the code below is thrown together; it is there to show you what to do. It will probably require some fixing before it works. The intent should be clear.

From what I read in your code, mostly what you are doing is setting the traffic lights in particular combinations, several times over, with delays in between.

In general, any time you do the same thing, conceptually, several times, it should either be in a loop, or in a function.

In this case, the first thing that (to me) looks like it belongs in a function is: `set all the lights in a particular pattern, and wait for a while`. I would call this function something like `set_lights_and_delay` (or, perhaps `setLightsAndDelay` depending on your coding style). It would take 5 parameters: the state of each light (red, green, or yellow/red, which I would just call yellow), and the time to delay (which may be 0). In this function, you would set ALL the pins, high or low, as appropriate (since your function shouldn't assume the previous state), then delay the appropriate amount of time.

```
enum colors {yellow, red, green, yellowred};

void loop()
{ 
    set_lights_and_delay(yellow,red,red,red,5000);
    if(analogRead(A0)>=THRESHOLD)
    {
      set_lights_and_delay(green,red,red,red,40000);
    } else {
      set_lights_and_delay(green,red,red,yellowred,30000);
    }
```

... and so forth (or whatever light combinations you want).

Now, how would you write this function? This function does the same thing for each light, so it sounds to me like you would want to make a function that takes a color, and the 3 pins to use:

```
void setLightsAndDelay(color northlight, eastlight, westlight, southlight; int delaytime)
{
    setOneLight(northlight, redLed1, yellowLed1, greenLed1);
    setOneLight(eastlight, redLed2, yellowLed2, greenLed2);
    setOneLight(westlight, redLed3, yellowLed3, greenLed3);
    setOneLight(southlight, redLed4, yellowLed4, greenLed4);
    delay(delaytime);
}
```

Now, setOneLight is pretty simple to write:

```
void setOneLight(color thisLight; int redled, yellowled, greenled)
{
    if (thisLight==green) // always do the easiest one first.
    {
        digitalWrite(greenled,HIGH);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(greenled,LOW);
    }

    if (thisLight==yellow) || (thislight==yellowred)
    {
        digitalWrite(yellowled,HIGH);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(yellowled,LOW);
    }

    if (thisLight==red) || (thisLight==yellowred)
    {
        digitalWrite(redled,HIGH);
    } else {
        digitalWrite(redled,LOW);
    }
}
```

In practice, there would be a lot of other things I'd do: I'd put all the things I know about a single traffic light into a struct; this means I could pass the struct to a function, in one go. I'd put the four traffic lights in an array; this means I could go through them in a loop, rather than calling the same function 4 times individually (great when your city ends up with 1,000 traffic lights!). I would probably put the pattern of lights (green/30000, yellow/10000, red/30000, yellowred/10000) into an array (made a little more difficult by the sensor).